# SkyDrive permanent error "request_url_invalid"

Tags: rest, request, onedrive

I'm trying to use SkyDrive REST API accordingly to [Microsoft Live Connect docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243648.aspx#folder), in order, for instance, to get list of objects under specific folder of my SkyDrive account.
As they say, I should use the following GET request:

```
https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/FOLDER_ID/files?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

That's exactly what I do - replacing FOLDER_ID by real id and ACCESS_TOKEN by real access token

```
https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/folder.85a56ffb53c19f6d.85A56FFB53C19F6D!102/files?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

But every time I get the error in response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "code": "request_url_invalid", 
      "message": "The URL contains the resource 'folder.85a56ffb53c19f6d.85A56FFB53C19F6D!102', which isn't supported."
   }
}
```

I have tried another ways, another urls, but without success. Search on this error has given nothing as well.

Comment: Well, finally I've realized that there should not be the "me/skydrive/" in request url. Without it everything works like a charm.